# MySQL query for many to many with limit

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I want to get N news with offset O with all Tags

```
news
id | title

tag
id | name

news_tag
news_id | tag_id
```

How can I do it in a single query?

Now I get N news at first.

```
  SELECT * FROM news LIMIT N, O
```

And after get all tags for each news:

```
SELECT n.id, nt.tag_id, t.name FROM news AS n 
JOIN news_tag AS nt ON n.id = nt.news_id
JOIN tag AS t ON nt.tag_id = c.id
WHERE n.id = curNewsId
```

It is N+1 query. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT n.id, nt.tag_id, t.name 
FROM (SELECT id 
      FROM news 
      LIMIT N, O) AS n 
JOIN news_tag AS nt ON n.id = nt.news_id
JOIN tag AS t ON nt.tag_id = c.id
```

It should be noted that `LIMIT` applied without an `ORDER BY` clause will select an *arbitrary* set of records from `news` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't have 15 reputation to rate you.